# How to add user name on svn?

Tags: svn

I am new with svn. In mercurial, you can set

```
[ui]
username = coder <coder@example.test>
```

Then coder name will appear on central repo whenever he committed a revision. How to set that on svn ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The author is controlled by the server.  The authenticated username at the time of the commit is set as the svn:author revision property.  When committing to a file:// URL, where there is no server, the user is set from the current username from the OS.

If you'd rather store something other than just the username you can map usernames to whatever value you want to put in there by writing a hook.